# Hive - Adding 2 columns for each row with some null values

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have an SQL query where I am joining 2 tables, on another table  - A and B
Table A is being joined on table E on ID = ID 
Table B is being joined on table E on ID = SKU

Table A and Table B both have columns Price, Value

Sometimes there are null values in here

I have done Select ID, (A.Price + B.Price) AS TEST, (A.Value + B.Value) 
AS TEST2 from E

But I am getting NULL values for all of the results for test and test2

Query is:

```
select PII, PII_Count, SK_Count, (PII_Count - SK_Count) as TEST from CIEER
left join ccq on CIEER.PII = ccq.PRIE 
left join ccrq on CIEER.PII = ccrq.SKIE
order by PII_Count desc
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also, what results do you want?

Comment: I dont have any sample data that I can provide, but when I export the data in HUE it looks like the NULL value stays in the columns... I am trying to get Both added together and if either are NULL just get the value of the one that has a value and if both are null then leave it blank.

Comment: Put your actual query here. In above query you are not even joining with table A and B.

Comment: added query above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PII_count or SK_Count is null then it will return null ,to prevent null from calculation you should use `nvl` function like below:

```
(nvl(PII_count, 0) - nvl(SK_Count,0)) as TEST
```

Alternatively you can also use `COALESCE` function as well.